# Not able to mount multiple targets (subnets) to a EFS file share

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-efs

I am trying to create multiple mount targets using 3 subnet ids to a single file system through terraform. While running the code it is creating 2 file shares (the second one without a mount target) and then failing giving me the below error.

> Error: putting EFS file system (fs-0c479ab4b699829d1) lifecycle configuration: InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
> │ - missing required field, PutLifecycleConfigurationInput.LifecyclePolicies.

Here's my EFS code.

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
  creation_token   = var.efs_token
  performance_mode = var.efs_performance_mode
  encrypted        = true
  
  lifecycle_policy {
    transition_to_ia = "AFTER_30_DAYS"
  }

  tags = local.mandatory_tags

}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mount" {
  count = length(data.aws_subnets.private.*.id)
  depends_on = [aws_efs_file_system.efs]
  file_system_id  = "${aws_efs_file_system.efs.id}"
  subnet_id       = "${element(data.aws_subnets.private.*.id, count.index)}"
}

resource "aws_efs_backup_policy" "efs_backup_policy" {
  file_system_id = "${aws_efs_file_system.efs.id}"

  backup_policy {
    status = "ENABLED"
  }
}
```

This is the EFS lifecycle policy

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system_policy" "policy" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id

  bypass_policy_lockout_safety_check = true

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleStatement01",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Resource": "${aws_efs_file_system.efs.arn}",
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}
```

```
data.tf

data "aws_vpc" "this" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${local.name_prefix}-vpc"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "private" {

  count    = length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${local.name_prefix}-vpc-private*"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.this.id]
  }
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {}
```

```
tfvars

efs_token                        = "dev-load-test"
efs_performance_mode             = "maxIO"
```

Comment: What are your TF and aws provider versions?

Comment: Terraform v1.3.0 and provider version = "~> 4.5, != 4.6.0"

Comment: These are very old. Please upgrade and check.

Comment: The issue is still there. I don't think it's the version issue :(

Comment: In that case you have to provide values of ALL your variables, definitions of your subnets, vpc and everything which is required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i have added the data.tf and the values I am using. Cannot provide the resource code for subnet ids since I dont own that

Comment: Where is the VPC setup? You are using some custom VPC, so how is it defined? Subents? route tables, ...?

Comment: I am using the org level code and I dont have access to that. We are just importing the resources using data. I am sorry if this doesn't help